# How to enable eslint cache for create-react-app which takes too long to start?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, create-react-app, react-scripts

I've wondered why [my project](https://github.com/web-reprex/panel-jest-api-mocking) takes too long, I've checked some topics about it, now I think that it maybe is the `eslint cache` problem in `react-scripts`.

This is the result of `TIMING=1 eslint .`

```
Rule                                     | Time (ms) | Relative
:----------------------------------------|----------:|--------:
react/no-direct-mutation-state           |  1818.923 |    24.9%
react/no-typos                           |   812.661 |    11.1%
react/require-render-return              |   765.499 |    10.5%
unused-imports/no-unused-imports         |   592.197 |     8.1%
testing-library/await-async-utils        |   233.464 |     3.2%
no-whitespace-before-property            |   199.900 |     2.7%
testing-library/no-container             |   154.535 |     2.1%
testing-library/no-debug                 |   145.567 |     2.0%
testing-library/no-promise-in-fire-event |   123.937 |     1.7%
testing-library/await-async-query        |   120.638 |     1.7%
```

I wonder why  `yarn start`, won't generate the `eslintcahce`.

How can I fix this problem?